# React trying to pass async call into Props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-props

So what I'm trying to do is basically call an async function than ask mapStateIntoProps to pass it into props into the actual component. When I do I get a console.log() that shows pending my data is in there tho.

```
here is my first file that has the async func
   export const getIdMovie = async (state,movieId)=>{
  let data= await axios
  .get(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}? 
      api_key=${APIKEY}&language=en-US`
  )
  let results=data.data

  return results
}

this is where i try to call it on the second file
injectDataReducer(store, { key: "movie", reducer: MovieReducer });

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  movie: getIdMovie(state,ownProps.movieId)
});
```

[image: here is my console.log]

Comment: Use redux thunk. Redux thunk takes a promise function and does the resolve and props maping.

Answer (score 1):

If getIdMovie is an action creator, you will have to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).Reducer updates the store asynchronously when you dispatch and action to avoid changing same data by multiple dispatch actions.

````Also, you will have to first set the state i.e. movies into reducer and then update the data from there into your component.```